# Can I use Shopify Mobile Buy SDK to build android or ios app for shopify store?

Tags: android, ios, shopify

When I checked the documentation for Mobile Buy SDK, its looks like an SDK for shopping cart and native payment for custom built apps to integrate sales channel to Shopify.

But I have seen some endpoints to perform search operations, list products, create users and all. Does this mean I can use it for developing the entire app using Mobile buy SDK without developing custom API set using the Shopify Web SDK.

https://help.shopify.com/api/sdks/custom-storefront/mobile-buy-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. There are some sample apps here, built entirely with Shopify's Android Buy SDK and iOS Buy SDK:

https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android/tree/master/MobileBuy/sample

https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/tree/master/Sample%20Apps/Storefront

Comment: Tried this but the generated app is not working. Looks like some packages are missing.